# grep not finding blank lines on a particular file

Tags: grep

I preform the command grep '^$' myfile and receive no results.

In vi you can clearly see it list the following on line 2 of the file.  In vi I set number and set list and this is what that line looks like.

2 $

The previous line terminates with a $ too.  If I run it without the the ^ it returns every single line like you would expect.

I run the command on other files and it works, but not from files from a particular source.  The file is ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators, so are the others.

Not sure what else I can look at on this type of file that would affect these results.

*Looking in notepad++ looking at the hidden characters the problematic has CRLF at the end of the lines blank or otherwise.

The non-problematic one is just LF.

Somewhere in there is the problem just finding it difficult to craft a grep statement that figures this out.

*Took the problematic file and used dos2unix and grep -En '^$' myfile works now. Too bad I can't be editing this file for my ultimate fix.

*In the end this is what worked for this file type.

```
grep --color=never -n '^[^[:print:]]' myfile
```

Comment: I don't understand the dollar sign in your file: are you saying that your file contains lines, containing dollar signs, or just not (a dollar sign means "end of line" in `grep`)?

Comment: Have you checked for spaces at the end of the lines?  Trying grepping for `grep ' $' myfile` and see if there is trailing whitespace.

Comment: maybe there are some nonprintable characters? you can cat -A your file to display representation of those

Comment: @Dominique in vi if you use the set list command, End of lines are represented with a $. So if a line only as $ when viewed by vi that would appear as blank line if cat or view with a text editor.

Comment: @AndyLester tried that didn't find the line.

Comment: @MaciejWrobel  seems like that would be the same is viewing it with vi and set list, but that did give me a idea to look at it in a hex editor.  I will have to try that.

Comment: @MaciejWrobel cat -A show the blank line with ^M$.  Tried grep -n '^M$' myfile but no luck there either.

Comment: possibly you could try grep -e '^[^[:print:]]*$' which should print lines containing at most nonprintable characters?

Comment: That command just scrolls a bunch of black space in the terminal.  A few of the of the commands I crafted did the same thing.  Not sure what is up with that.   I tried adding color by setting color to always. No change  I sent that command to a file by adding >>greplog and in vi that file just has a bunch of lines  like this in it.

I tried to turn color to always and it did the same thing.  I 

^[[32m^[[K461^[[m^[[K^[[36m..........

Found that it appears those are color codes, set color to never and bang the file had results.

Stopped sending to a file still have results.

Comment: @MaciejWrobel Thank you that inspired me a bit to look into why some of the commands were spitting out blank space, not sure what is happening with the color deal but, turning the color off on the grep you gave me got me the results I was looking for.